# Transpose '$x$' in $y =\frac{1}{2}x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain how I shall transpose this:

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x$$

I shall get '$x$' alone, I am stuck on this one for some kind of reason, 
and would be glad if someone helped me out.

In addition:

Can someone please confirm if these steps are correct for this
(NOT related to the above):

$$y = \frac{1}{2}x - 7$$

$$y + 7 = \frac{1}{2}x - 7 + 7$$

$$2(y + 7) = \frac{1}{2}x \cdot 2$$

$$x = 2y + 14$$

Comment: **1/2x** could be read as $\dfrac12 x$ or as $\dfrac1{2x}$

Comment: Aha, didn't know that. So one can multiply by 1/2 on both sides to get x = 1/2y, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you don't need this any more, nearly two years later. Anyway, your second example is correct. For your first, just double both sides.